# Building a form wizard and need to validate parts of the greater form… possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a `<FormWizard />` component that looks roughly like this:

```js
const FormWizard = ({
    children,
    defaultValues,
    onSubmit,
}) => {
    const formMethods = useForm({ defaultValues });
    const {
        formState: {
            errors,
            isSubmitting,
            isValid,
        },
        handleSubmit,
    } = formMethods;

    return (
        <FormProvider { ...formMethods }>
            <form
                noValidate
                defaultValues={ defaultValues }
                onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) }
            >
                {
                    Children.map(children, child => {
                        if (isValidElement(child)) {
                            return (
                                <FormWizardPanel>
                                    {
                                        cloneElement(child, {
                                            errors,
                                            inWizard: true,
                                            isSubmitting,
                                            isValid,
                                        })
                                    }
                                </FormWizardPanel>
                            );
                        }
                        return child;
                    })
                }
                <StyledCTABar>
                    <Button
                        disabled={ !isValid }
                        label="Submit"
                        type="submit"
                    />
                </StyledCTABar>
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    );
};
```

The `children` passed in are just form components that look roughly like this:

```js
export const FormSignup = ({
    errors,
    inWizard,
    isSubmitting,
    isValid,
}) => {
    return (
        <fieldset>
            <Input
                required
                disabled={ isSubmitting }
                error={ errors?.email?.message }
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                type="email"
            />
            <Input
                required
                disabled={ isSubmitting }
                error={ errors?.password?.message }
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
            />
            {
                !inWizard ? (
                    <StyledSubmit
                        aria-label="Sign Up"
                        disabled={ !isValid }
                        icon="arrow-right"
                        iconPosition="after"
                        label="Sign Up"
                        loading={ isSubmitting }
                        type="submit"
                    />
                ) : null
            }
        </fieldset>
    );
};
```

In the `<FormWizard />` example you’ll see a `<FormWizardPanel />` component being used. Each child form passed in gets wrapped in this component, and each represents a step in the wizard. Each “step” can contain anywhere from 0 to `n` required fields, and all steps include at least one form input.

I need to be able to validate the form one `<FormWizardPanel />` at a time. Say if `<FormWizardPanel />` number 1 has three required fields, and all are valid, I need to enable a “Next” button that allows the user to move to the next panel. If `<FormWizardPanel />` number 2 has one required field that isn’t valid, I need to disable the “Next” button. And so on…

**Is it possible to check for partial validation of a bigger form with react-hook-form?**

Now, I’m *sort of* able to pull this off by using IntersectionObserver and only requiring required fields when they enter the viewport, but this is easy to hack by just going into the inspector and changing the panel’s CSS `transform` value.

Comment: Hi, are u able to do the partial validation?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this, and I broke up every step into its own form and its own component with its own `useForm` hook while passing the data between them by using `useState` in the main component, and set the `defaultValues={data}` on every form on the `useForm` hook.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import OrderFormProgress from './OrderFormProgress'
import OrderFormStep1 from './OrderFormStep1'
import OrderFormStep2 from './OrderFormStep2'
import OrderFormStep3 from './OrderFormStep3'
const OrderForm = () => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0)
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    address: '',
    aptSuitNumber: '',
    betweenStreets: '',
    zipCode: '',
    whatEver: '',
  })
  const handleNextStep = async (newData) => {
    setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...newData }))
    setCurrentStep((prev) => prev + 1)
  }
  const handlePrevStep = async (newData) => {
    setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...newData }))
    setCurrentStep((prev) => prev - 1)
  }
  const SubmitHandler = async (values: any) => {
    console.log(values)
    // submit data...
  }
  const steps = [
    <OrderFormStep1 key="Step1" next={handleNextStep} data={data} />,
    <OrderFormStep2
      key="Step2"
      prev={handlePrevStep}
      next={handleNextStep}
      data={data}
    />,
    <OrderFormStep3
      key="Step3"
      prev={handlePrevStep}
      next={SubmitHandler}
      data={data}
    />,
  ]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OrderFormProgress
        currentStep={currentStep}
        setCurrentStep={setCurrentStep}
      />

      {steps[currentStep]}
    </div>
  )
}
export default OrderForm
```